# Programmatically select a row in CGridView‎

Tags: gridview, yii

How can I set the selection for the row displaying a new record in CGridview of Yii.

For example: Upon adding a new record user is redirected to the grid view page, where it displays all records. Now i want to show the new record as selected/highlighted in gridview.

Comment: when my page load the new record should be selected without any click.

Comment: can you add more details, I am not able to understand what you are asking.

Comment: i have add a new record and after it the page is redirect to my grid view page. where it display all records, now i want to show my new record as selected/highlight in gridview.

Comment: And what You want to do with selection? Or You want just visual differens of old records?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add in main.css

   ```
   .grid-view table.items tr.newrecord {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000 !important; /* red color is new record */
   }
   ```
2. In model of message

   ```
   function isNeedSelection()
   {
       return (strtotime($this->created) > time() - 5*60); // 5 minutes
   }
   ```
3. In CGridView add row css class expression

   ```
   'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->isNeedSelection()?"newrecord":$this->rowCssClass[$row%2]',
   ```

Comment: as an extra note, the default selection css class is `selected`, so incase you want, you can just add `selected` to this new record instead of `newrecord`

Comment: @bool.dev new record flag is reset when record has been saved, it's not will work.